# Loading driver jar file at runtime resulting in Perm Gen Space Error

Tags: java, tomcat, permgen, urlclassloader

I have created a REST service in which I am loading the JDBC driver jar at runtime. Below is the code which does this:

```
Driver driverInstance;
URLClassLoader driverClassLoader;
driverClassLoader = new URLClassLoader (new URL[] { "c:/mysql.jar" }, System.class.getClassLoader());
Class<?> driverClass = driverClassLoader.loadClass("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = driverInstance.connect(connectionString, userDbCredentials);
```

After using this connection to load data into database, I am closing the **connection** and **driverClassLoader** both. But after running it for some time, I am getting 
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space** in tomcat server.

I took the heap dump, and open it using eclipse Memory Analyzer and I found that the below Leak suspect message:
**13 instances of "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader", loaded by "java.net.URLClassLoader @ 0xc155fc10" occupy 14,083,776 (32.21%) bytes**

I understand that it is due to loading of driver jar at runtime but I am unable to find a solution to it.

Comment: Is the driver in the libs/ folder of tomcat?

Comment: No, it is read from an external path.

Comment: Where exactly is that code executed? Is the classloader creation only done once per driver, or for each time a certain call is done?

Comment: Code is executed in the contructor. I tried both, loading once, and loading for each call.

Comment: Are you aware that [JDBC drivers don't need to be explicitly loaded anymore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)?  If you place mysql.jar in WEB-INF/lib or in Tomcat's library directory, you can replace all of that code with one line: `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, userDbCredentials);`.  Doing away with explicit loading of the driver class may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the JDBC driver class, it registers itself with `java.sql.DriverManager`. Even though you try to make the system classloader the parent of your `URLClassLoader`, I believe it will inherit the `AccessControlContext` from your `WebappClassLoader`, thus referencing it. Analyzing the references using Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT) could help verify that - [see this blog post for instructions](http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/).

Assuming that the JDBC driver is in fact the source of the leak, the solution to your problems is to call `java.sql.DriverManager.deregisterDriver()` to explicitly deregister the driver, preferably in the `contextDestroyed()` of a `ServletContextListener`.

Normally you could let my [ClassLoader leak prevention library](http://github.com/mjiderhamn/classloader-leak-prevention) take care of the deregistering for you, however since the driver is loaded in a separate classloader it won't work out of the box. You may however be able to do some subclassing/modification. The benefit would be that you get a lot more leak protection for free.

Whether you really want and need to load drivers from outside the application at runtime - well, that's a separate question...

Good luck!